# IE9 SmartScreen Filter warning

Tags: internet-explorer-9, code-signing, smartscreen

My company develops an IT-infrastructure management software, that we mostly use in Ukraine.

Our client application installer is available for download from our FTP server.

Whenever someone downloads an Install.msi from our FTP, IE9 tells the user that the package isn't commonly downloaded, therefore may be dangerous. In order to run the install the user has to click "Other options" which most users simply won't do due to security risks fears, given such "first impression" by IE9.

Our install package is signed by a valid code signing certificate, which already ensures some level of confidence for a user.

How can someone "comply" with IE SmartScreen filter, so that warning will no longer be in the way of product distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/22/smartscreen-174-application-reputation-building-reputation.aspx