# Signing exe with certificate doesn't solve the display of smartscreen

Tags: ssl-certificate, code-signing, smartscreen

I'm developing C++ program. I generate a certificate from our PKI Solution configured in our company(Microsoft). I sign my .exe using the certificate(generated). But when I make my file on the server (internet) and download it, I have the problem of displaying SmartScreen.What should I do to make my .exe works well in all computer of our company? Should I buy a certificate to sign my code? Sign my code with root certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is your application has downloaded a few users and the reputation is unknown to Microsoft

P.S. And you can distribute your program in Microsoft Store

Comment: But I have recompiled the code and  change the name of application but I'm always behind the problem of SmartScreen

Comment: Your can read "Best Practices" topic, for more info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates/

Comment: [Same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582603/ie9-smartscreen-filter-warning?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks , I know that i have to sign my application and I signed it with certificate generated from local PKI solution. Our browser are supposed to accept any information signed from PKI .But in case of this exe , always it displays SmartScreen .So should I buy certifcate ?

Comment: Yes and you need: Extended Validation Code Signing for Microsoft 

P.S. Standart validation doesn't garantee SmartScreen Application Reputation 

P.S.2. You can test this behavior in my application: http://strongsvn.com